# scp using ssh tunneling

Tags: scp, ssh-tunneling

Usually, I would just do `scp file myuser@server1:~/` (and enter my password)
but now I need to first `scp file myuser@server2:~/` and then `ssh myuser@server2` from me into server2, and then from server2 do the `scp file myuser@server1:~/`

I tried to do `ssh -L 8888:server1:22 myuer@server2` and it asked me the password just as it does when I do `ssh myuser@server2`, and it just connected to server2 but not to server1.

How can I make it work so that I could `scp` from me directly to server1?

Answer (score 5):

You can very simply configure the `ProxyCommand`/`ProxyJump` so you will be able to `scp` directly to the distant server. Create a `~/.ssh/config` with the following:

```
Host server1
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p server2
```

and then you will be able to scp directly:

```
scp local.file server1:/path/to/remote.file
```

If you really insist on port forwarding then after creating a "tunnel" using the first command you provided:

```
ssh -L 8888:server1:22 server2
```

you will need to trasnfer the data this way (where the `-P` indicates the port where the forwarded connection is set up):

```
scp -P 8888 local.file server1:/path/to/remote.file
```

Answer (score 2):

`scp` supports a remote source file as well as a remote destination file. It uses ssh for data transfer, so this should be equivalent to your attempts at tunnelling:

```
scp file myuser@server2:~/
scp myuser@server2:~/file myuser@server1:~/
```

By the way, if `myuser` is the same username as your local login, you can omit it:

```
scp file server2:~/
scp server2:~/file server1:~/
```

If you really do want a tunnel (so the file never needs to touch the `server2` filesystem) then this is answered well here: https://superuser.com/questions/276533/scp-files-via-intermediate-host

So well in fact, that this might be considered already answered...

Comment: In the link I tried `"Tunnel" through B`. but what does `localhost:destination` mean? It's not A\B\C...

Comment: Took me a while to grok it too. `localhost` is literal, while `destination` is the name of the destination path. So in your case after your `ssh -L 8888:server1:22 myuer@server2` you would do: `scp -P 8888 file localhost:~/`

Answer (score 2):

I find this this very handy:

```
scp -J myuser@server2 file myuser@server1:~/
```

Also, if you keep the user names equal between your laptop and each of the servers, you can simply leave out the user name. If you like, you can also put server2 in your hosts file (/etc/hosts)  with a nice and short name for faster typing :

```
# in file /etc/hosts 
74.125.71.113 s2  # this is server2
```

Then the command for transfering `file` to server1 is:

```
scp -J s2 file server1:~/
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in ~/.ssh/config of the host server

```
XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth

Host remote
  User foo
  Hostname remote-server
  ProxyCommand ssh foo@gateway-server -W remote-server:22
```

then scp as

```
scp remote:~/file_to_be_copied .
```